# About Database development, what variant is better?

Tags: sql

I am creating a database of school gradebook. I have 2 tables: Class and Teacher. And i have a problem. A teacher needs to be a form-master of class. How should i make this relationship?

**Variant 1:** 
**Class** will have a **teacherId** property.

**Variant 2:** 
**Teacher** will have a **classId** property.

What variant is right?

Comment: How many classes can a teacher teach if a teacher teaches classid?

Comment: How many teachers can a class have? Exactly one? Zero or more?

Comment: What's a form-master?

Comment: One teacher - one class

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*3 types of relationships are possible, generally speaking:*

**One-to-many**

- If a class can have many teachers, but a teacher can only teach one class, then put `ClassID` on the Teacher table.

**Many-to-many**

- If a class can have many teachers, and a teacher can teach many classes, then make a 3rd table, `TeacherClassLink` and put both `ClassID` and `TeacherID` in it, as well as an identity column like `TeacherClassID` -- as per the comments, this is known as a `cross reference table` although I always call them link tables, unofficially.

**One-to-one**

- If each teacher can only teach one class, AND each class can only have one teacher, then you can make `TeacherID` and `ClassID` be the same value in both tables.

---

In your example,

**Variant1** is a one-to-many relationship where each class can have only one teacher, but each teacher can many classes..

**Variant2** is a one-to-many relationship where each class can multiple teachers, but each teacher can only have one class.

*Based on the business needs of your application, you should decide which of the options to choose.*

Comment: This is a great answer, but I really think the OP should opt for the Xref table.  This allows for *so much* more flexibility down the road.

Comment: A very good point and I agree with you. There are always considerations such as having additional joins when querying the data; so if for example the school always only has one teacher per class, an xref table may not be needed.

Comment: @EvanL: An XRef table should only be used in the event that you believe that teacher/class assignments should be many-many (imho).

Comment: I agree, and following YAGNI you are correct.  However, what happens when the school grows and decides that they are going to redo their current structure to allow multiple teachers etc... Now they have to completely restructure the tables to accomodate.

Comment: Not completely restructure. I believe you hit the nail on the head with *YAGNI* :)

Comment: That is the quintessential question of over-engineering upfront vs. refactoring later ;)

Comment: _"considerations such as having additional joins "_ - for the given use, the performance penalty of joins (if any) is most likely neglectable, and having to write them should not be an issue when using an ORM.

Comment: @DavidKhaykin True enough.

Comment: @CodeCaster: I work on systems where we have so many M2M tables just trying to find some simple relationship takes like 12 joins... so I was thinking in that context.

Comment: @DavidKhaykin precisely where I was coming from as well.  Our DB has far too many as well.  For the poster's purposes, I assume leaving an Xref out would probably be fine.  I was just trying to stir the pot... and I did ;)

Comment: Hey I'm always down for a good discussion! Hopefully OP will chime in soon.. I want to know what a form-master is :)

Answer (score 0):

Making the assumption that a specific class is taught by one teacher and that a teacher can typically teach more than one class you will want to add a TeacherId to the class entity.

Answer (score 0):

Variant 1 allows for much more flexibility. With this variant, you can have multiple classes with the same teacher ID.

```
class Class {
   int TeacherId {get; set;} // this is absolutely necessary
   // other properties
}
```

Plainly speaking, a teacher is assigned to a class or classes.
If Teacher contains the class Id, then how much data gets duplicated when the same teacher teaches 3 different classes?

Comment: So if you have beginner music, intermediate music and band, the teacher Id will be in all 3 of those Class(es). Would you rather list the teacher 3 times with a class Id for each, or simply add a TeacherId to the Class table?

Comment: I'd rather use a join table to establish a many-to-many relationship, since you asked...